# Handle exceptions caused by message-converter on Message Driven Inbound Channel Adapter

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-jms

In the configuration below I have a `message-driven-channel-adapter` with a `message-converter` so the `service-activator` is invoked with the converted payload.

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="myConsumerChannelAdapter" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                                        destination="input_queue" channel="input_channel" error-channel="errorChannel"
                                        message-converter="messageConverter" header-mapper="jmsHeaderMapper" acknowledge="client" max-concurrent-consumers="10"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="input_channel" output-channel="output_enricher_channel" ref="MyConsumer"/>
```

If an exception is thrown by `MyConsumer` it will be send to the `errorChannel`. So far it works as intended.
But when the message converter throws an exception like `MessageConversionException` it is not send to the `errorChannel`. If I log exceptions caused by message-converter I get:

```
AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(875) | Execution of JMS message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
```

But how can I assign an `ErrorHandler` to my Channel Adapter or send those exceptions to my `errorChannel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be available in the upcoming 4.2 release.

https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3670

[Commit here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/e7534aa4b88a0a199b1ebfcbb0d2877a5f97012d).

The [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792971/query-regarding-spring-message-driven-channel-adapter) for which I raised the JIRA has a (sort-of) work-around, but it's a bit kludgy.

You can try 4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT for testing; there will be a milestone in the next few weeks, but the final release is not planned until towards the end of the summer.